# Generate sequence of argument to pass to a program?

Tags: bash

I'm currently using combination of curly brackets and globing to play multiple files in vlc at once:

```
vlc K20-{06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}*
```

But the numbers are alway full sequence, is there a way to somehow specify it a bit simplier, maybe something like

```
vlc K20-{06-17}*
```

? Maybe use `seq` somehow?

I can use

```
   $ echo K20-{$(seq -s, -f "%02.0f" 06 17)}*
K20-{06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}*
```

but that does not seem to expand the `*`. Any way around it?

Comment: The syntax for a brace expansion range is `{m..n}` - so `K20-{06..17}*`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @steeldriver notes, `K20-{06..17}*` covers it.

Example, using an `echo` for test/validation:

```
$ echo vlc K20-{06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}*
vlc K20-06* K20-07* K20-08* K20-09* K20-10* K20-11* K20-12* K20-13* K20-14* K20-15* K20-16* K20-17*
$ echo vlc K20-{06..17}*
vlc K20-06* K20-07* K20-08* K20-09* K20-10* K20-11* K20-12* K20-13* K20-14* K20-15* K20-16* K20-17*
```

The `*` will be expanded as well if there are files that match the name in the present working directory.

So `vlc K20-{06..17}*` will achieve what you want.

More information on bash expansion at [GNU Bash Reference Manual - Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). Or from `man bash`, read:

> A  sequence  expression  takes  the  form  {x..y[..incr]},  where  x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.

So:

```
$ echo K20-{06..10}
K20-06 K20-07 K20-08 K20-09 K20-10

$ echo K20-{06..10..2}
K20-06 K20-08 K20-10
```